# How to redirect requests from one applications to another running in different Kubernetes clusters based on http status codes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, istio, traefik, linkerd

There are **two clusters**.
There are **two applications**.
All requests first go to a **primary app** in one cluster.
If the primary app **knows the request** (non 404 http response code) it responds appropriately.
If the primary app **doesn't know the request** (404 http response code) it redirects the request the **fallback secondary app** running on a **different cluster**.

Is there a tool (e.g. service mesh) with which this scenario could be implemented and how?